# ssis 2014 import data from mdb and convert

Tags: sql-server, ssis, system-integration

I've a column data type text(16) in a .mdb like date type (ex. '31/01/2000') and I'm trying to convert to datetime. 
If I set output column (in advanced editor)datatype from datatype [DT_WSTR] to [DT_DATE] it's work but some records are 'null' and I don't know why.
This is the schema (simple schema):

[date column] datatype TEXT(16) --> Data Source=\xxx.MDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 --> 
data flow  --> source ole db --> [date column] datatype DT_WSTR --> modify/error output --> ignore -->
advanced editor --> properties I/O --> external columns [date column] datatype DT_WSTR -->
output columns [date column] datatype [DT_DATE] --> destination ole db --> [date column] datatype [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]

I tried using data conversion and derived column task with errors (cast and Others...).

And If I import DT_WSTR as is in the modified table as nvarchar(16), return an error about length (50!), and if i set nvarchar(50), these records are still 'blank'!

What i can do? I need an idea...

Comment: Give sample of data you want to convert to date, maybe there are in different format between your db and data dd-mm-yyyy vs mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: I'm thinking about substring from datepart, but cannot try now...

Comment: All work now! The mdb was not sync to other files... thank you for help.